# Deploy to password-protected meteor app without typing the password each time?

Tags: meteor

I've password-protected my meteor app, but would like to avoid typing a password each time I deploy. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use a deploy bash script to deploy my site by drawing from a `password.txt` file containing the password (and ignored by git!). For example:

```
echo "Deploying..."
echo
meteor deploy mysite.com < password.txt
echo "Done."
```

The full script I use is available on Github here:
https://github.com/Q42/q42.nl/blob/develop/deploy.sh